# cast<int> method in c# is not type casting

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I had to convert a string to int array first by splitting string by comma,then convert to int array.

and following line is working fine

```
 int[] array = input.Split(',').Select(obj=>Convert.ToInt32(obj)).ToArray();
```

but i wanted to do this in different way using cast extension method.

```
int[] array = input.Split(',').Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

but using cast extension it is throwing invalid cast operation exception.

I even applied ofType() prior to cast that is not really required but still its not working.

```
int[] array = input.Split(',').OfType<string>().Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

What mistake I am making here.

I am using cast method in appropriate manner.

Comment: @peter please read my question first

Comment: For the `Cast<T>()` method to work, the object has to be of the correct type already. The `Cast<T>()` method only reinterprets the data, it doesn't do any conversion. See the marked duplicate for correct techniques in C# for parsing a string as an `int`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, so it doesn't type cast, then why it is named cast

Comment: It does cast. But the casting operator in C# does two different things, depending on context: reinterpreting, and conversion. The method is named for the cast operator in its reinterpreting sense, not the conversion sense. Frankly, your question would best be answer by you reading the C# language documentation, to learn about the cast operator, and the MSDN documentation, to learn about the `Cast<T>()` method. All the answers are in there.

Comment: And note that _even if the `Cast<T>()` method did support the conversion sense of casting in C#_, it still wouldn't work because there's no explicit conversion defined from `string` to `int`. You have to use a parsing method regardless (e.g. `int.Parse()`).

Comment: @PeterDuniho if it were to be doing type casting, then it could have used int.parse internally and returning the same. Anyhow, I got my problem. I perceived it as casting method rather it is similar to OfType(). only exception it throws exception if set doesn't all the item of same type.

Comment: You are completely missing the point. The word "cast" has multiple meanings in programming. You are stuck on just one meaning, and ignoring the fact that even in that meaning of the word, neither the language nor the framework has no mechanism for doing what you want. The method is well-named, and does exactly what the name suggests it does.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am sorry if I am looking adamant to you. I admit I had misconception regarding this cast word and it may be the case with other dumb people like me as well as because not everybody is geek or intelligent like you. So, why don't you put your comment as answer. So, in future someone has same misconception, then it will clear their doubts. thanks Peter for valuable support.

Comment: You can also use following method:

int[] array = Array.ConvertAll(input.Split(','), Convert.ToInt32);

Answer (score 1):

You should  use `int.Parse` to convert a `string` to `int`. In C#, a string is **not** being able to be casted directly into integer.

```
input.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()
```

Comment: what is the mistake cast method of course I do have a working query already. Why I can't use cast method

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following method.

```
int[] array = Array.ConvertAll(input.Split(','), int.Parse);
```

Comment: Of course, I can my question what is wrong with Cast method

Comment: @YogeshJoshi `Cast<T>` will not work in your case. `Cast<T>` is the extended method of `IEnumerable` interface and the type of your string array is `IEnumerable<string>`. for example if you cast the array to enumerable by using `AsEnumerable` method then you will see the  type of the array will be `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>`